# Definition of semantic consequence relation for substructural logics

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**How does one define the semantic consequence relation for substructural logics? What options are available.**

First a word on notation. Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the integers greater than or equal to zero. Also, I will only use set-builder notation in the form $\{v : \varphi(v)\}$ where $v$ is a variable to prevent ambiguity about variable scope.

---

**What follows is my attempt to define $\models$ for a simple substructural logic.**

---

For concreteness, I'm looking at a very simple substructural logic defined by the following inference rules. Let $\Gamma$ be a sequence of propositions. Let $\Gamma \vdash S$ be equivalent to $\cdots \Gamma_2, \Gamma_1, \Gamma_0 \vdash S$.

$$ \frac{\Gamma, A \vdash B}{\Gamma \vdash A \to B} \;\; \text{is implication introduction} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash A \to B \;\;\text{and}\;\; \Gamma \vdash A}{\Gamma \vdash B} \;\;\text{is implication elimination} $$

And suppose we have the following tautology $\vdash A \to A$.

None of these rules are contraclassical or contra-intuitionistic (if we squint and pretend that $\Gamma$ is a set), so it seems clear that the consequence relation $\vdash$ is nontrivial.

I think we can get a definition for $\models$ by looking at the usual definition and tweaking it.

$ \Gamma \models S$ would normally hold if and only if, for all structures $M$ such that $M \models \Gamma$ holds, $M \models S$ holds.

In this setting, I'll make $M$ have a $\mathbb{N}$-valued notion of time. Let $[P]^M_t$ denote the value of the propositional constant $P$ at time $t$.

So, $M \models \Gamma_0, \Gamma_1, \cdots$ if and only if $\{ z : z = [\Gamma_n]^M_n \land n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ consists exclusively of designated truth values.

And thus $M \models S$ if and only if $M \models \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is the singleton sequence consisting of $S$ alone.

This definition sort of works and gives us a generalization to $\Gamma \models \Delta$.

It's kind of unsatisfying though for two reasons.

- We don't need to jump through hoops like this when $\Gamma$ is merely a set. Each proposition letter just gets a single truth value.
- If I want to add a new structural rule like exchange, the only way I can do this is by completely changing what $\Gamma$ is (i.e. making it a multiset). So this semantics doesn't seem very friendly for doing an apples-to-apples comparison between similar systems with different structural rules.

Comment: The relevant section of the [SEP article on substructural logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/#4) might be of interest.

Comment: Just to be clear: Is your goal to cook up a semantics $\models$ so that $\models$ is equivalent to $\vdash$ in your restricted system?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that too. My goal after that is try to make a semantics for type systems where the terms use De Bruijn indices (if that idea even makes sense). But for now I'm just trying to define $\models$ in a reasonable way for logics where the context $\Gamma$ is weird and doesn't look like a set.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something in the definition of your logic, it seems to me that you can only prove $\vdash A\rightarrow A$, and so the logic is trivial: (1) You have no rule which introduces a formula on the left hand side, so in any provable sequent $\Gamma=\emptyset$. (2) As a consequence, implication introduction is never applicable. Then you can show by induction that whenever $\vdash B$ is provable, then $B$ is of the form $A\rightarrow A$.